# Vue.js - Dynamic progress bar with inline style binding

Tags: javascript, css, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a progress bar that will change the background color according to a "v-for" list source data. The data is: *(attributes from 0 to 10)*

```
plants: [
    { name: 'Rosemary', sun: 7, water: 3, care: 3 },
    { name: 'Pepper',   sun: 8, water: 4, care: 6 },
    ...
  ]
```

I've tried this:

```
<div class="card-bar-sun"> //Main grey bar
  <span :style="{ width: calc(plant.sun * 10) + '%'}"></span>
</div>
...
```

How could be the method logic for this?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question in full. If you are just looking for a way to calc the percentage you can use this:

```
<div class="card-bar-sun"> 
  <span v-for="plant in plants" :style="{'width': calcBar(plant) + '%'}"></span>
</div>
```

Js:

```
calcBar(plant) {
   //or more complicated stuff
   return plant.sun *10
}
```